# AWS CDK: How to create an IAM role that can be assumed by multiple principals?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm deploying a Lambda function that will be used by CloudFront. The execution role for the function therefore needs to be assumed by edgelambda.amazonaws.com and lambda.amazonaws.com. If I was doing this by hand, the policy would look like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": [
                "edgelambda.amazonaws.com",
                "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
    ]
}
```

When setting this up in AWS CDK, the `iam.Role` class only allows you to specify one assuming principal initially, e.g.:

```
lambda_role = iam.Role(
    self,
    "lambda_redirect_role",
    assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("edgelambda.amazonaws.com"),
    managed_policies=[
        iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"),
        iam.ManagedPolicy.from_aws_managed_policy_name("AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess")
    ],
)
```

So I'm trying to find the best/cleanest way of adding the second principal. The documentation says that I can use [assume_role_policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/Role.html#aws_cdk.aws_iam.Role.assume_role_policy) to retrieve the policy document and then manipulate that.

So I've tried:

```
policy = lambda_role.assume_role_policy
policy.add_statements(
    iam.PolicyStatement(
        actions=["sts:AssumeRole"],
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        principals=[
            iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com")
        ]
    )
)
```

but that gives me this rather less-than-optimal policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried manipulating the existing statement within the policy but I can't figure out how to then get that back into the Role definition:

```
policy = lambda_role.assume_role_policy
# This gives us a read-only policy so we need to do
# some manipulation in order to add the lambda principal
policy_json = policy.to_json()
print(policy_json)
# That gets us a dict (even though it says json) so now
# we extract the one and only statement ...
statement = policy_json["Statement"][0]
# Turn it back into a CDK object we can manipulate
statement_obj = iam.PolicyStatement.from_json(statement)
# Add the extra principal
statement_obj.add_principals(
    iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com")
)
# Put it all back ...
policy_json["Statement"][0] = statement_obj.to_json()
policy.from_json(policy_json)
```

Is there a way to get to the "cleaner" policy statement with CDK or am I stuck with the two statements it is currently generating?

Comment: If you are using CDK, why are you worry about it's build code ? Just follow CDK way to write IAM role, which should be easy to read and extend. I generally created IAM role with  `ServicePrincipal` which will invoked by some resources automatically and then create `PolicyStatement` statement for each service that this role will use. It provides extensibility in terms of lets say in future I need to add/remove service, it can be done without actually harming the existing policy

Comment: @AtulKumar you make a fair point. The reason I was trying to get to the desired policy was for consistency with existing roles and trust policy statements. Most of our existing infrastructure has been deployed by hand so I wanted to be as consistent with that design/look as possible.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This can be done using [CompositePrincipal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_iam/CompositePrincipal.html):

```py
lambda_role = iam.Role(
    self,
    "lambda_redirect_role",
    assumed_by=iam.CompositePrincipal(
        iam.ServicePrincipal("edgelambda.amazonaws.com"),
        iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    ),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you! `CompositePrincipal` solved it for me:

Comment: This works, but is there a way to combine each principal into one statement?  `CompsitePrincipal` builds multiple statements instead of a single statement containing multiple principals.

Answer (score 1):

Use case: I intended to add multiple account principals to the trusted relationship along with the service principal so that the permissions are not wide open. I was able to solve it using [spread operator](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_es6_spread.asp).

```js
    const accountsToAllowAssumedBy = ['000000000000', '111111111111'];

    const role = new iam.Role(this, 'Role', {
      roleName: 'AssumeRoleTest',
      assumedBy: new iam.CompositePrincipal(
        new iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'),
        ...accountsToAllowAssumedBy.map((account) => new iam.AccountPrincipal(account)), //Spread Operator (...)
      ),
    });
```

Output:

```json
"Role1ABCC5F0": {
   "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
   "Properties": {
    "RoleName": "AssumeRoleTest",
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
     "Statement": [
      {
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
         "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root",
         "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
        ],
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
       }
      }
     ],
    },
   },
  },
```